# file upload sent to database and immediately shown into gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

what i want to happen is display the uploaded file in a grid view (working fine) and send the same file to the sql database (working fine).

My main task is to get all the uploaded file under the person who is currently logged in. for example customerA logs in, only uploaded files of customer A will be shown.

I already managed to get the session user and store it in database
[image]

having that in my database, i now implement a select statement. (here is where my problem starts) here is the page load code:

```
public static string cs = "Server=PAULO;Database=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security=true";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                con.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM DepositSlip Where Username = '" + Session["New"] + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                Label2.Text += Session["New"].ToString();
                linkLogout.Visible = true;
                linkOrderHistory.Visible = true;
                Label2.Visible = true;
                linkViewProfile.Visible = true;

                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
                List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
                }
                GridView1.DataSource= files;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand that its loading up the files from the directory path but what i don't know is how to implement to show the uploaded files FROM the database based on the session user.

The problem is that it shows the same data regardless of the who logged in.

any tricks on this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Server='server_name';Database='database_name';Trusted_Connection=True;";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; i++)
    {

        String insertData = "INSERT INTO Import_List(Fname, Lname, Age) VALUES (@Fname, @Lname, @Age)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        da.InsertCommand = cmd;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

This should work just as well.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source='server_name';Initial Catalog='database_name';Trusted_Connection=True;");
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
    string connection = "Data Source=Excel-PC;Initial Catalog=Northwind.MDF;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "Fname");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "Lname");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "Age");

            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Import_List";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt.CreateDataReader());
        }
    }

}
```